# Kubernetes cluster architecture

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-cluster

Does it make sense to create a separate ***Kubernetes*** cluster for my *Cassandra* instances and one cluster for the *application layer*? Is the DB cluster accessible from the service cluster when both are in the same region and zone?

Or is it better to have one cluster with different pools - one pool for the service layer and one pool the DB nodes?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `pool`?

Comment: Ivan: in gcloud you create a cubernetes cluster and assign a pool of machines to this cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a toss-up or opinion in terms of how you want to design your whole architecture. Here are some things to consider:

Same cluster:

- Pros

  - Workloads don't need to go to a different podCidr to get its data.
  - You can optimize your resources in the same set of servers.

    - This is one of the main reasons people use containers orchestrators and containers.
    - It allows you to run multiple different types of workloads on the same set of resources.
- Cons

  - If you have an issue with your cluster running Cassandra you risk losing your data. Or temporarily lose data if you have backups. (Longer downtime)
  - If you'd like to super isolate the db and app in terms of security, it may be harder.

Different clusters:

- Pros

  - 'Safer' if one of your clusters goes down.
  - More separation in terms of security for your data at rest.
- Cons

  - Resources may not be optimally utilized. Leaving some CPUs, memory, etc idle.
  - More infrastructure management.

Different node pools:

- Pros

  - Separation of data at rest
  - Still going through the same PodCidr.
- Cons

  - More management of different node pools.
  - Resources may not be optimally utilized.